# Why does the '\n' get stored as one item using a for loop?

Tags: python, string, iteration

This question mostly has to do with me wanting to better understand how python works.

So I just made a simple function that is a more dynamic version of the `.split()` function, (it allows for multiple splits, one of which is the `'\n'` so I can better format some CSV information) but I don't know exactly why one aspect of it works. When you iterate through a string, such as `"Hello there!\nGeneral Kenobi."`, with a for loop, such as - `for letter in string`, why would the `'letter'` variable store `'\n'` as one string, rather than `'\'` and in the next iteration `'n'`?

Code that I know does this:

```
myString = "This is a string\nThis is a string"
for letter in myString:
    print(repr(letter))
```

Just to be clear, I love that it does this, but I just want to know why.

Thanks!

Comment: '\n' *is* a single character - it's character number 10 in ASCII, called 'line feed' or 'newline'. It's just displayed as '\n' to make it more readable.

Comment: `"\n"` is a string with a single newline character, not a string with a backslash and an `n`. See also [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).

Comment: The `repr` (representation) of some special characters (newline, tab, emojis etc) is designed to be 'strict'. E.g. the repr of a backslash is '\\'.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html

Comment: If you want two characters for "\n" then use a *raw string*: `myString = r"This is a string\nThis is a string"`

Answer (score 2):

Because it *is* one character. The `\` generally is an "escape" character in many contexts, meaning that it and the following character(s) are not literally part of the string, but instead are a representation of a character or other structure that doesn't have a written representation or can't easily be rendered faithfully in that context (such as a newline). A literal `\n` in a string would be rendered as `\\n`, in fact (where the `\` *itself* has to be escaped, to indicate that it's a *literal* `\`).

Comment: "\n" are still two characters, even though they are interpreted as just one in the context of (non raw) string literals

Comment: @NicolaSap that depends on what you consider a "character". What you see on screen *looks like* two characters, but Python stores it internally as one and treats it as such in all contexts.

Comment: That makes sense, I was originally thinking it was how the for statement operated but I was wrong. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Within a string literal ([reference page for python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)), escaped characters, *i.e.* those that are prepended by a backslash "`\`", are replaced and interpreted according to some rules. You can force python to interpret "\" (backslash) as a single character by prefixing the string literal with a letter "`r`" or "`R`".

So "`\n`" is actually two characters in your source code, but it is interpreted as the ASCII character "LINE FEED" by python

### A note on user input

String passed with **Python2's `input()`** are treated in the same way as string literals (strings that you define within the code by just writing them between quotation marks). In both cases, "`\n`" is interpreted as a single LINE FEED character.

On the other hand, **Python3's `input()` and Python2's `raw_input()`** read raw string, *i.e.* "`\n`" is interpreted as two characters.

So if in your example (I'm assuming Python3) you use

```
myString = input()
```

and give "`This is a string\nThis is a string`" as a input, then the for loop would iterate on "`\`" and "`n`" separately.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between what we see as a "character" and what python sees, we see `\` and `n`, each with its own meaning. Python reads however `\n` since `\` means* ignore next character. So python reads `\n` not `\` and `n`. This `\n` is for python the "End of line", so we should not interprete this as `\n` (`\`, `n`) but as `end of line`(enter).

*oversimplefied